# How to update item of Model Class in ArrayList that goes into RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a Model Class to store user chats info

```
public class UserChat {

private String ownerid;
private String ownername;
private String receivername;
private String message;
private Long time;
private Long oldtime;
private String seentick;

public UserChat() {
}

public UserChat(String ownerid, String ownername, String receivername, String message, Long time, Long oldtime, String seentick) {
    this.ownerid = ownerid;
    this.ownername = ownername;
    this.receivername = receivername;
    this.message = message;
    this.time = time;
    this.oldtime = oldtime;
    this.seentick = seentick;
}

public String getmessage() {return message;}

public void setmessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}....
```

Initially, I am retrieving data from `onChildEvenListener` and add into an ArrayList.

```
    userchatlist = new ArrayList<UserChat>();
    chatrecyclerAdapter = new ChatRecyclerAdapter(userchatlist);
    mchatlist.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mchatlist.setAdapter(chatrecyclerAdapter);

    mChatRoom.child(useruid).child(useruid + "_" + receiver_uid).child("ChatList").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "childadded");

            userchats = new UserChat();

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("message")){
                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "messageoo " + message);
                userchats.setmessage(message);
            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("ownerid")){
                String ownerid = dataSnapshot.child("ownerid").getValue().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "owneridoo " + ownerid);
                userchats.setownerid(ownerid);
            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("ownername")){
                String ownername = dataSnapshot.child("ownername").getValue().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "ownernameoo " + ownername);
                userchats.setownername(ownername);
            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("receivername")){
                String receivername = dataSnapshot.child("receivername").getValue().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "receivernameoo " + receivername);
                userchats.setreceivername(receivername);
            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("seentick")){
                String seentick = dataSnapshot.child("seentick").getValue().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "seentickoo " + seentick);
                userchats.setseentick(seentick);
            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("oldtime")){
                Long oldtime = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("oldtime").getValue();
                Log.d(TAG, "oldtimeoo " + oldtime);
                userchats.setoldtime(oldtime);
            }

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("time")){
                Long time = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue();
                Log.d(TAG, "timeoo " + time);
                userchats.settime(time);
            }

            userchatlist.add(userchats);
            chatrecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

However, I want to update the ArrayList items whenever there is a change in the item named "seentick" that triggers the onChildChanged.

```
@Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged");

            if(userchatlist!=null){

                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("seentick")){
                    String seentick = dataSnapshot.child("seentick").getValue().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "seentickooxx " + seentick);
                    chatrecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //HOW TO UPDATE userchatlist???

                }

            }

        }
```

How can I update only the item "seentick" in the ArrayList, not `clear()` and `add()` the whole list again??